# Why doesn't my get-method return the assigned value to my key?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I've been assigned the following task in my Datastructures and Algorithms course, and I have no idea why it does not work.

The task is to implement a Linked Hashtable. I have created two classes, one that acts as the key <-> value pair, representing an element (Entry class), and the Hashtable class that has the methods (currently only put and get), but I can't seem any of them to work. The Hashfunction method was provided by our teachers, so I can't answer any questions regarding that.

Whenever I execute the program, I get no errors, but the list returns empty. Anyone here who can guide towards the right direction of where I am doing wrong? I assume the error lies within the put method, but I can't seem to figure out where to issue might be.

Best regards,
Victor

```
 package Laboration2;

/**
 * A class that works as a container for the key and value.
 * 'Entry' will become an element in our hashtable
 *
 * @author Victor Marante
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 2016-09-22
 */
public class Entry {

    private Object key;
    private Object value;
    private Entry next;

    public Entry(Object key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Entry keyToCompare = new Entry(obj, null);
        return key.equals(keyToCompare.key);
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Entry getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Entry next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Class that holds all the methods for the Hashtable itself:

```
package Laboration2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * Created by Victor on 22/09/16.
 */
public class Hashtable {

    private LinkedList<Object> insertionOrder = new LinkedList<Object>();
    private LinkedList<Entry>[] table;

    // Constructor that initiates a hashtable
    public Hashtable(int size) {
        table = (LinkedList<Entry>[]) new LinkedList<?>[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            table[i] = new LinkedList<Entry>();
        }
    }

    // Hashfunction
    private int hashIndex(Object key) {
        int hashCode = key.hashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode % table.length;
        return (hashCode < 0) ? -hashCode : hashCode;
    }

    public Object get(Object key) {
        int hashIndex = hashIndex(key);
        LinkedList<Entry> entries = table[hashIndex];
        Iterator<Entry> it = entries.listIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry entry = it.next();
            if (entry.equals(key)) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void put(Object key, Object value) {
        int hashIndex = hashIndex(key);
        LinkedList<Entry> entries = table[hashIndex];
        Iterator<Entry> it = entries.listIterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry entry = it.next();
            if (entry.equals(key)) {
                entry.setValue(value);
                insertionOrder.add(value);
            } else {
                entry.setNext(new Entry(key, value));
                insertionOrder.add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hashtable table = new Hashtable(15);
        table.put("hej", "hello");
        table.put("nej", "no");
        table.put("senare", "later");
        table.put("idag", "today");
        table.put("igår", "yesterday");

        table.get("hej");
    }
}
```

EDIT1 (for Krishas comment):

```
public void put(Object key, Object value) {
        int hashIndex = hashIndex(key);
        LinkedList<Entry> entries = table[hashIndex];
        Iterator<Entry> it = entries.listIterator();

        if (table[hashIndex] == null) {
            table[hashIndex] = new LinkedList<Entry>(key, value);

        } else {

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Entry entry = it.next();
                if (entry.equals(key)) {
                    entry.setValue(value);
                    insertionOrder.add(value);
                } else {
                    entry.setNext(new Entry(key, value));
                    insertionOrder.add(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged through your code, and found where exactly it's not behaving as you expect it to?

Comment: Note that your `Entry.equals` method is pretty odd - you'd normally compare one *Entry* with another not a key. (It's asymmetric.) Overriding `equals` without overriding `hashCode` is unusual too.

Comment: Wouldn't your `equals` method be easier written as `return Objects.equal(obj, key);`? (No need to create an `Entry`)

Comment: I think you need to override hashCode method also. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java.

Comment: Both the Hascodefunction and the Equals method was provided to us by our teacher, so I wouldn't know unfourtanetly

Answer (score 1):

#### What is wrong

That is indeed because of your put method. Your call to `setNext` is in the wrong place, and this has 2 consequences:

- since the list is initially empty, `it.hasNext()` will return false, and you will never add anything to the list
- even if you managed to add something to the list, you are calling `setNext` only if the **first** key in the list doesn't match. So you are always discarding the second element.

I think some of your I clarity comes from your confusing the two kinds of lists you are handling here: one is the lists inside the table, whose purpose is to handle collisions, meaning different keys ending up in same index of table. The other one is the global list, whose purpose is to record the order of insertion.

For the first type, you don't need 'setNext', you only need to 'add' to it. SetNext is actually meant for the secon type (see below).

#### What you should do

You should add a new entry only if after processing the whole list there is no match (which also includes the case where the list is empty), meaning after your `while` loop.

#### Other notes on your code

- you can simplify your iteration on your list by using the `for-each` statement. Instead of writing

  ```
  Iterator<Entry> it = list.iterator();
  Entry entry;
  while(it.hasNext()){
     entry = it.next();
  ```

  You can write

  ```
  for(Entry entry : list){
  ```
- it seems to me that your code as it is posted doesn't compile, since you are `redefining` the variable `entry` several times. You should define it outside the loop, and only assign values to it in the loop.
- as mentioned by others, the `equals` method of your `Entry` class is uselessly complex. You can replace your code by:

  ```
  return key.equals(obj);
  ```
- you don't need your `insertionOrder` list. The whole point of having a `next` field in your `Entry` class, is to be able to link entries so you can iterate on them based on insertion order. All you need to record is the head of the list (the first `Entry` as well as the tail of it (the latest inserted `Entry`), so you can link from it.

#### End result for your `put` method

```
public void put(Object key, Object value) {
    int hashIndex = hashIndex(key);
    LinkedList<Entry> entries = table[hashIndex];

    for(Entry entry : entries) {
        if (entry.equals(key)) {
            entry.setValue(value);
            // You might want to update listTail here too
            return;
        }
    }
    Entry newEntry = new Entry(key, value);
    entries.add(newEntry);
    listTail.setNext(newEntry);
    listTail = newEntry;
}
```

Comment: I might be stupid or just exhausted, but isn't that what I am doing? The way it works, in my mind that is, is if the key exists, add the value to that key, and only the value.

If the key doesn't exist, create a key, and add said value to that list?

Comment: When `it.hasNext()` is false from the outset, you never get into the loop to the if-else statement where you are doing one or the other. So in the end, nothing gets done.

Comment: @Marante, did this answer solv your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your put method doesn't insert any element to the table, Because there is no element in the linkedList in the initial stage.

```
final int hashIndex = hashIndex(key);
    final LinkedList<Entry> entries = table[hashIndex];   //Here entries will be empty on first insert
    final Iterator<Entry> it = entries.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {    // it.hasNext() will returns false, so loop exits without inserting value to the table
        final Entry entry = it.next();
        if (entry.equals(key)) {
            entry.setValue(value);
            insertionOrder.add(value);
        } else {
            entry.setNext(new Entry(key, value));
            insertionOrder.add(value);
        }
    }
```

In this code the table will be empty when you insert the first element. so the iteration will exit without inserting anything to the table.
Hence get returns null.

You can use something like this,

```
public void put(final Object key, final Object value) {
    final int hashIndex = hashIndex(key);
    final LinkedList<Entry> entries = table[hashIndex];
    final Iterator<Entry> it = entries.listIterator();
    //
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        entries.add(new Entry(key, value));
    } else {

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            final Entry entry = it.next();
            if (entry.equals(key)) {
                entry.setValue(value);
                insertionOrder.add(value);
            } else {
                entry.setNext(new Entry(key, value));
                insertionOrder.add(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this is just for the current issue, I'm not sure about your intention.

Comment: Okey I see the issue now, thanks!

However, how do I add an Entry in that case? I have made an edit to the original post, but it doesn't work. I get errors on this line:

    table[hashIndex] = new LinkedList<Entry>(key, value);

Comment: Again you have checked
    if (table[hashIndex] == null) 
this won't be null, as I mentioned earlier it should be an empty LinkedList initially.
I'm not sure about your intention, If you want to add element to the LinkedList you can write something like this,
        if (!it.hasNext()) {
            entries.add(new Entry(key, value));
        } else {
//your while loop
        }

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this(I commented to make it clearer):

```
    public void put(Object key, Object value) {
    if (get(key) == null) { //If the key does not exist
        int hash = hashIndex(key); //Hash the key
        Entry<Object> e = new Entry<Object>(key, value); //create new Entry
        table[hash].add(e); //At the hashed index, add new entry,
        insertionOrder.add(value); //Add value to insertionOrder
    }
}
```